# html web shows header only in mobile view

Tags: android, css, html

I am adding a functionality to my Android app with a WebView. The problem is, I removed the header and it succesfully disappeared, but when I see it from my smartphone (WebView) it is still there...

the website is [this](http://moma-soft.es/avalanche/forecast/) (I'm not posting the html/css here because it's too long)

This is how it looks from my phone :S

[image: web from mobile]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fixed-navigation.css on line 17, you have:

```
#content {
    padding: 60px 0 0;
}
```

The top padding is what you are seeing.

To debug such problems in the future, I would recommend using [Chrome's built-in user-agent switcher.](http://techdows.com/2011/12/google-chrome-now-has-built-in-user-agent-switcher.html)

Comment: thanx, that was it... But why didn't it show up in my pc browsers?

Comment: I didn't look into it that much, but perhaps it was in a @media rule targeting mobile devices.